# Ran `sudo apt-get -f install` and it removed almost everything including essential packages

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, dpkg, elementary-os

I was trying to install zoom using dpkg. Then, I got `ibus` error, so I installed the required package `libxcb-xtest0`. After that it required another package, but I forgot the package name. When I installed that package it suggested that I run `sudo apt-get -f install`. My bad for not reading, I ran the command and it uninstalled almost everything including core packages.

Now, I am accessing the OS via tty1 and and followed this comment from stackoverflow https://serverfault.com/a/646116 in an attempt to restore what was removed. Unfortunately, it didn't work as expected. Please see supporting images.

Currently I have no idea what else I could do. If possible I don't want to resolve it by reinstalling the OS.

Supporting Images: https://bit.ly/2SqNzTj

Comment: You seem to have lost name resolution, and as a result you can't access any repositories on the internet. If you can't repair name resolution (it may be sufficient to put the clause `nameserver 1.1.1.1` into /etc/resolv.conf) I would download the appropriate Ubuntu installation DVD, connect it to the broken system and perform the installation from that DVD. This requires a second computer that is able to burn a DVD or copy an ISO file to a USB drive.

Comment: The network-manager got deleted as well and the desktop and a bunch of others. Anyway, I already fixed this. Thanks for your attempt to help. Appreciated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone who will encounter this problem. Here's what I did to fix this daunting accident.

Since my `network-manager` had also been removed there is no way `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`, `sudo apt-get -f install` nor `sudo apt-get upgrade` works no matter how many times I tried.

Thankfully, I found my thumb drive with bootable Kali Linux in it. You can use other Debian/Ubuntu distro to boot as Live CD and follow instructions from [**here**](https://adityagilra.blogspot.com/2019/05/ubuntu-reinstall-network-manager.html?m=1) on how to install the `network-manager` via Live CD. **NOTE:** I only followed how to install the `network-manager` then I exited and rebooted to my main OS.

Afterwards, I'm back to my main OS, I still can only access `tty1` but with internet access, I can now install everything that got removed. For this, I ran `sudo apt-get update -y` first and then ran the bash script which I created from the earlier attempt I mentioned in the post, which I followed from [**here**](https://serverfault.com/a/646116).

After the install was completed I rebooted and viola! Everything was recovered as if nothing happened.

Hope this could help somebody. But, I hope even more that you don't encounter this.